My chessboard has no color, how do I add color to the boxes or spaces of it?
I am making a Chess game, atm I am making a chessboard and was about to finish when I realized that it has no color and was like...
"How do I add color?"
Heres the code, where and how do I add color to this chessboard?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Chess V.1" << endl;

    int size = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                cout << "[  ]";
            Represents black squares
            else cout << "|  |";
            Represents white squares
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

return 0;
}

I tried to add this in the cout boxes...
cout << "\033[40m\033[37m[  ]\033[0m";

it well of course didnt work, I know for sure Im lacking something...

Don't use using namespace std;, it is bad practice.. Just qualify cout and endl with std:: instead.

Also, hardcoding some ANSI specific escape sequences is a terrible recipe for anything except if being ANSI terminal compliant is the goal. Just do not.

I closed your question as a far-fetched duplicate, but it was to get you to not follow the path of any of the answers you've gotten.

Stafan: If you would be happy with a platform specific answer, please specify what platform you are using.

There will be an OS-or-terminal-specific solution that fits your needs, but frankly I don't think Ted's pitch of an ncurses duplicate is too far-fetched.

I'm guessing you're on windows? If so you'll need to enable vt escape sequences https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Use:
if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
    cout << "\033[47m\033[30m  \033[0m";
else
    cout << "  ";

See Colorizing text in the console with C++.

If your answer is mostly a link to another question then you should flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer

You can try something like this:
int main() {
int size = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
            // Black square
            cout << "\033[40m\033[37m[  ]\033[0m";  //this makes the background black and text in the background white.
        } else {
            // White square
            cout << "\033[47m\033[30m[  ]\033[0m";  // opposite of the previous one
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

return 0;}


The escape sequences you've given are the same as the ones they say they've already tried and didn't work so this is unlikely to solve their problem
